# DebuggerStepThrough equivalent for Java

Tags: java, debugging, jvmti, jdi

.NET has a couple of handy annotations that instruct a debugger to step through/over certain methods. I would like to know if there is an equivalent that works on the Java platform.

For instance:

```
@DebuggerStepThrough
public void foo() {
  ..
}
```

would cause the debugger to **not** stop in `foo` when stepping.

#### What I tried

- using the SYNTHETIC flag in the classfile. This causes javac to forbid user-code calling such methods.
- custom attributes. There is no [JDI API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/) to retrieve annotations. Also mentioned on [this forum](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=6369885).

PS. I am implementing a debugger and have control over the bytecode that is emitted

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, not as a stock feature, no.

Otherwise I can also recommend having a look at eclipse debugger's "Step filter" and "conditional breakpoint" features. It allows you to ignore certain types (step filter) or only halt on certain runtime conditions (conditional breakpoints).

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I was looking for. I wanted a platform-level annotation, avoiding the need for me to implement step filters for my language (essentially duplicating the work that the Java IDE team did already for Java). In the meantime I know there is no such thing.